# Model is unable to Predict due to a type error, applying a model on UTF-8 encoded URDU Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, utf-8, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to run an algorithm on an URDU dataset, I have a Logistic regression model for english but runs in to errors when I try to use it on Urdu Language UTF-8 encoded dataset.

I have applied the code given below on the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
import logging
from gensim.models import word2vec
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from scipy.sparse import hstack
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
from tqdm import tqdm
from scipy import sparse
import numpy 
#import score
import re, nltk, scipy

#import gensim
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier,BaggingClassifier,VotingClassifier,AdaBoostClassifier,GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

dataset1 = pd.read_csv("fakenews.csv", encoding = 'UTF-8')
ds = dataset1.copy()
print(ds.shape)
df = ds.copy()

df = ds.copy()
df.drop('FileName',axis=1,inplace = True)
df.drop('label',axis=1,inplace = True)

da = ds.copy()
da.drop('FileName',axis=1,inplace = True)
da.drop('title',axis=1,inplace = True)
da.drop('text',axis=1,inplace = True)

def extract_word_overlap(title, text):
    word_overlap = []
    for i, (title, body) in tqdm(enumerate(zip(title, text))):
        #preprocess_headline = preprocess(headline)
        #preprocess_body = preprocess(body)
        features = len(set(title).intersection(text)) / float(len(set(title).union(text)))
        word_overlap.append(features)
        word_overlap_sparse = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(numpy.array(word_overlap)) 

    return word_overlap_sparse

def combine_features(tfidf_vectors, word_overlap):
    combined_features =  sparse.bmat([[tfidf_vectors, word_overlap.T]])
    return combined_features

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split   
x_train, x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(df,da, test_size = 0.3,random_state=42)

training_bodies = x_train['text']
training_headlines = x_train['title']

test_bodies = x_test['text']
test_headlines = x_test['title']

print("\t-Extracting tfidf vectors..")

body_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))
bodies_tfidf = body_vectorizer.fit_transform(training_bodies)

headline_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))
headlines_tfidf = headline_vectorizer.fit_transform(training_headlines)


bodies_tfidf_test = body_vectorizer.transform(test_bodies)
headlines_tfidf_test = headline_vectorizer.transform(test_headlines)

training_tfidf = scipy.sparse.hstack([bodies_tfidf, headlines_tfidf])
test_tfidf = scipy.sparse.hstack([bodies_tfidf_test, headlines_tfidf_test])



training_overlap = extract_word_overlap(training_headlines, training_bodies)
test_overlap = extract_word_overlap(test_headlines, test_bodies)
training_features = combine_features(training_tfidf,  training_overlap)    
test_features = combine_features(test_tfidf, test_overlap)



print("[3] Fitting model..")
print("\t-Logistic Regression")

lr = LogisticRegression(C = 1.0, class_weight='balanced', solver="lbfgs", max_iter=150) 


y_pred = lr.fit(training_features, y_train).predict(test_features)


from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score, f1_score
print('classification report:')
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

print("Accuracy of Regression:   %0.3f" % score)

print('Macro f1:', f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro'))
print("[4] Evaluating model..")
score.report_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
"""
```

i expected the model to predict but it give me a type error. TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

```
761: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "<ipython-input-1-800030f783cf>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/door/Desktop/af/pycode.py', wdir='C:/Users/door/Desktop/af')

  File "C:\Users\door\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\door\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/door/Desktop/af/pycode.py", line 101, in <module>
    y_pred = lr.fit(training_features, y_train).predict(test_features)

  File "C:\Users\door\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py", line 1286, in fit
    check_classification_targets(y)


  File "C:\Users\door\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 168, in check_classification_targets
    y_type = type_of_target(y)

  File "C:\Users\door\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 287, in type_of_target
    if (len(np.unique(y)) > 2) or (y.ndim >= 2 and len(y[0]) > 1):

  File "C:\Users\door\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 233, in unique
    ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)

  File "C:\Users\door\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 281, in _unique1d
    ar.sort()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Dataset i am using looks like this

```
FileName    title   text    label
0001a   میں استعفیٰ نہیں دے رہا   فیاض الحسن چوہان  "صوبائی وزیر اطلاعات فیاض الحسن چوہان نے کہا ہے کہ میں استعفیٰ نہیں دے رہا اور نہ مجھ سے استعفیٰ مانگا گیا ہے  مجھے محتاط بیان دینے کا کہا گیا ہے 
اور میں نے اپنی بیان میں ہندو مذہب یا ہندو برادری کو نہیں بلکہ بھارتی فوج اور بھارتی میڈیا کو مخاطب کیا تھا"    Agree
```

Comment: read each column as string using `dtype` , also check for missing/balnk values.

Comment: @Shijith found no missing/blank values.

Comment: can you check your `text` column , does it have `"` in the data? may be an issue there

Comment: @Shijith all sorts of punctuation marks have been removed, checked again too Text column does not have " in the data.

Comment: Can you please include the full traceback, so it becomes clear which line causes the error? Apparently, there is a comparison between a string and a number, but it's way too much code to spot the bug as-is.

Comment: @lenz kindly have a look now.

Comment: The traceback is all the lines that come after "Traceback (most recent call last):". Please include that too. The data-conversion warning you show seems to be a different (non-critical) issue.

Comment: @lenz question has been edited, complete Traceback is now included.

Comment: Ok. I can see the error occurs at the line `y_pred = lr.fit...`. And the error suggests that not all features are converted to numbers. But I can't see why. The only help I can provide is this suggestion: Keep reducing code to the absolute minimum that still produces this error. If you still can't solve the problem by then, update the question again or post a new one. Good luck!